# Display two edit fields for a value in Add/Edit Form jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need your help. I have a `jqgrid` table in which I need to have a `checkbox` and `textbox` for all the rows while adding/editing the row. Please check this screenshot:

[image: demo]

I need to implement the same functionality in my jqgrid table. Is it possible? Please help me with this.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your script create a checkbok and text field and prepand and append the checkbox and textfield respectively

```
$("#tableid tbody tr td").prepend("<input type='checkbox'>");
$("#tableid tbody tr td").append("<input type='text'>");
```

You can also check my jsfiddle Example below

http://jsfiddle.net/achuakshuu/noLczwec/